# Updating thumbnail of UIDocument in iCloud

Tags: swift, icloud, uidocument

I have a `UITableViewController` which displays a list of `NSMetaDataItem`s which are connected to a `StoryDocument` which subclasses `UIDocument`. Each `StoryDocument` has a `UIImage` property called `image`. Each row shows it's thumbnail.

I've overridden `fileAttributesToWrite(to: URL, for: UIDocumentSaveOperation)` to save the thumbnail as follows:

```
override func fileAttributesToWrite(to url: URL, for saveOperation: UIDocumentSaveOperation) throws -> [AnyHashable : Any] {
    let thumbnailSize = CGSize(width: 1024, height: 1024)
    if let thumbnail = image?.at(targetSize: thumbnailSize) {
        return [
            URLResourceKey.hasHiddenExtensionKey : true,
            URLResourceKey.thumbnailDictionaryKey : [
                URLThumbnailDictionaryItem.NSThumbnail1024x1024SizeKey : thumbnail
            ]
        ]
    } else {
        return [:]
    }
}
```

I set the thumbnail in `func tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)` where url is the url `metadataItems.value(forAttribute: NSMetadataItemURLKey)`

```
do {
    var thumbnailDictionary: AnyObject?
    let nsurl = url as NSURL
    try nsurl.getPromisedItemResourceValue(&thumbnailDictionary, forKey: URLResourceKey.thumbnailDictionaryKey)
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = thumbnailDictionary?[URLThumbnailDictionaryItem.NSThumbnail1024x1024SizeKey] as? UIImage
} catch {
    cell.thumbnailImageView.image = nil
}
```

If I change the `StoryDocument`'s `image` in a detail view and then return to the `UITableViewController`, the original thumbnail (unchanged) is still shown, even though I'm telling the `UITableView` to `reloadData()`. The image only updates about 10 seconds later, when the next `.NSMetadataQueryDidFinishGathering` or `.NSMetadataQueryDidUpdate` notification comes in. Is there a good way to get the recently changed thumbnail for the cell rather than the old one?

I'm using Swift 4, although I expect I could adapt suggestions in Swift 3 too.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the check. So, should I be preferring a resource item or a promised item? I've updated my code to use `nsurl.getResourceValue(&thumbnailDictionary, forKey: URLResourceKey.thumbnailDictionaryKey)` and I'm still getting the old thumbnail, rather than the thumbnail of the image I've just set.

Comment: Just to clarify: Seeing as I'm editing the UIDocument locally and setting the thumbnail, I would hope to be able to get the updated thumbnail instantly (or at least with no network delay) but I'm currently getting a 10 second wait.

Comment: Additionally, I'm sorting the tableView using using `URLResourceKey.contentModificationDateKey` and these two seem to be out of date until the notification comes in.

Comment: Sorry, when I mentioned 'setting' the image, I meant settings the `UIImage`'s image property. Thanks for the suggestion about using `URL` over `NSURL`. I didn't find the `getResourceValue` functions on them so I went backwards but `URL`'s `resourceValues` etc. are much cleaner.